# How to get data from database with query - Service Builder

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I start to create a Service Builder. I created some columns as bookTitle, then I add some book and finally I show this book like this ...

```
BookLocalServiceUtil.addBook(user_id, book_title) // there is another way how to add
BookLocalServiceUtil.getBook(book_id).getTitle()
```

But do you know how to use a clasic query? And it is possible? like

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name"
```

thanks

Comment: For those who want to create Service Builder in liferay - good documentation [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/service-build-2)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it implementing a custom finder and writing your own custom sql queries.

documentation [here](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Service+Builder+Finders)